# Minimising latency for users via AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, latency

I am newbie to AWS. I am using AWS Lambda for my project. How do I minimise the latency rate for my website users.  I want to execute my backend logic from the nearest instance/server to the users. I have heard Route 53 can do this.  How do i configure that.

Comment: Look into Route 53 geolocation routing.  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html)

Comment: If your content can be cached look into CloudFront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are concerned about geolocation-driven latency, I assume you are expecting these lambda functions to be called from multiple different regions. If so, you can use a combination of Route 53 and API Gateway to accomplish your goals.

> Many customers are looking to run their services at global scale, deploying their backend to multiple regions. In this post, we describe how to deploy a Serverless API into multiple regions and how to leverage Amazon Route 53 to route the traffic between regions. We use latency-based routing and health checks to achieve an active-active setup that can fail over between regions in case of an issue. We leverage the new regional API endpoint feature in Amazon API Gateway to make this a seamless process for the API client making the requests. This post does not cover the replication of your data, which is another aspect to consider when deploying applications across regions.

Detailed walkthrough: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/